# How to create a MAP that has an application scope? And Where to declare it?

Tags: java, cdi

I need to create a Map that has application scope. And so, if user1 add to this Map an object using method1 of class1, user2 would find the new objects using method2 of class2.

I know there is this annotation :

```
@ApplicationScoped
```

But, I don't know where my map should be declared or used, to make it have the same state at anytime and by anywhere in the application deployment time.

An example representing a class where this Map is declared and a method of another class using it, would be so helpful.

Comment: Are you working with JSF or CDI?

Comment: Declare and manage it inside a global singleton object?

Comment: @DanTemple avoid usage of singleton **ever**.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, I work by CDI, sir.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare a CDI bean that will provide this `Map` for its consumption:

```
@Named
@ApplicationScoped
public class ApplicationScopedBean {
    private Map<KeyClass, ValueClass> map;
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        //initialize the map and its data here
        map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
        map.put(..., ...);
        //...
    }
    //provide a getter for the map
    public Map<KeyClass, ValueClass> getMap() {
        return this.map;
    }
}
```

Now, the bean can be injected in clients and can show the data in your view.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your experience with Java language. But why don't you create a static variable in class?

So, for example:

```
class A {

  public static Map<String, String> globalMap;

}
```

From class B you could access or set it anywhere(ofcourse you need to import the class A at the top):

```
class B {

  public void doAnything(){
    Map anyMap<String, String> anyMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    anyMap.put("anyString", "anyString");
    A.globalMap = anyMap;
  }

}
```

Comment: A static variable is not application-scope, but classloader-scope. That's not always the same thing. Static constructs are often misused within JEE applications...